# Can I use "stopsignal=WINCH" to have supervisord gracefully stop an Apache process?

Tags: apache, supervisord

According to the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/stopping.html#gracefulstop), the WINCH signal can be used to gracefully stop Apache.

So it would seem that, in supervisord, I should be able to use stopsignal=WINCH to configure supervisord to stop Apache gracefully.

However, Google turns up 0 results for "stopsignal=WINCH". It seems odd that no-one has tried this before.

Just wanted to confirm: is stopsignal=WINCH the way to get supervisord to stop Apache gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running/stopping `apache2` under `supervisord` inside a Docker container. I don't know if your problem is related to Docker or not, or how familiar you are with Docker. Just to give you some context: when calling `docker stop <container-name>`, Docker sends `SIGTERM` to the process with PID 1 running inside the container ([some details on the topic](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)), in this case `supervisord`. I wanted `supervisord` to pass the signal to all its programs to gracefully terminate them, because I realized that, if you don't gracefully terminate `apache2`, you might not be able to restart that because the PID file is not removed. I tried both with and without `stopsignal=WINCH`, and the result didn't change for me. In both cases `apache2` was gently terminated (exit status was 0 and no PID file in `/var/run/apache2`. To stay on the safe side, I kept the `stopsignal=WINCH` inside the `supervisord` config, but as of today I was also not able to find a clear answer online, neither here nor by googling.

Answer (score 0):

According to the supervisord's [source](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/datatypes.py) code:

```
# all valid signal numbers
SIGNUMS = [ getattr(signal, k) for k in dir(signal) if k.startswith('SIG') ]

def signal_number(value):
    try:
        num = int(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        name = value.strip().upper()
        if not name.startswith('SIG'):
            name = 'SIG' + name
        num = getattr(signal, name, None)
        if num is None:
            raise ValueError('value %r is not a valid signal name' % value)
    if num not in SIGNUMS:
        raise ValueError('value %r is not a valid signal number' % value)
    return num
```

It does recognize all signals and even if your signal name doesn't start with 'SIG', it will add that automatically too.